# Android app error “Unfortunately App has Stopped” - New to programming

Tags: android

As I am new to programming, I am having a hard time finding the problem in my code. I would appreciate your help. I know I got the NullPointerException but I cant find the solution:

....

Thanks a lot all! I changed it. But it still gives me this (*note I tried to add sound. But even if I exclude the MediaPlayer, it doesnt work):

```
11-26 08:41:30.356: I/ActivityManager(371): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.thenewboston.christoph/.Splash} from pid 531
11-26 08:41:30.486: E/SoundPool(371): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-26 08:41:30.486: W/AudioService(371): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-26 08:41:30.496: E/SoundPool(371): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-26 08:41:30.496: W/AudioService(371): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-26 08:41:30.506: E/SoundPool(371): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-26 08:41:30.506: W/AudioService(371): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-26 08:41:30.506: E/SoundPool(371): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-26 08:41:30.506: W/AudioService(371): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-26 08:41:30.506: E/SoundPool(371): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-26 08:41:30.506: W/AudioService(371): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-26 08:41:30.506: E/SoundPool(371): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
11-26 08:41:30.506: W/AudioService(371): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
11-26 08:41:30.506: E/SoundPool(371): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
11-26 08:41:30.506: W/AudioService(371): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
11-26 08:41:30.506: E/SoundPool(371): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
11-26 08:41:30.516: W/AudioService(371): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
11-26 08:41:30.516: E/SoundPool(371): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
11-26 08:41:30.516: W/AudioService(371): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
11-26 08:41:30.516: E/SoundPool(371): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
11-26 08:41:30.516: W/AudioService(371): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
11-26 08:41:30.516: W/AudioService(371): onLoadSoundEffects(), Error -1 while loading samples
11-26 08:41:30.586: D/gralloc(52): Registering a buffer in the process that created it. This may cause memory ordering problems.
11-26 08:41:30.586: E/libEGL(52): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
11-26 08:41:30.596: E/libEGL(52): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
11-26 08:41:30.596: E/libEGL(52): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
11-26 08:41:30.596: E/libEGL(52): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
11-26 08:41:30.596: E/SurfaceFlinger(52): glCheckFramebufferStatusOES error 552518609
11-26 08:41:30.596: E/SurfaceFlinger(52): got GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES error while taking screenshot
11-26 08:41:30.596: E/libEGL(52): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
11-26 08:41:30.596: E/libEGL(52): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
11-26 08:41:30.596: W/WindowManager(371): Screenshot failure taking screenshot for (328x583) to layer 21005
11-26 08:41:30.626: I/Choreographer(531): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-26 08:41:30.886: I/Choreographer(371): Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-26 08:41:31.196: W/ActivityManager(371): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{b1fee0f8 u0 com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher t1}
11-26 08:41:31.406: I/ActivityManager(371): Start proc com.thenewboston.christoph for activity com.thenewboston.christoph/.Splash: pid=2391 uid=10051 gids={50051}
11-26 08:41:31.436: D/dalvikvm(2391): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
11-26 08:41:32.956: I/Choreographer(371): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-26 08:41:33.746: D/LightsService(371): Excessive delay setting light: 3798ms
11-26 08:41:33.996: D/dalvikvm(2391): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 43K, 4% free 3033K/3148K, paused 58ms, total 60ms
11-26 08:41:34.026: I/dalvikvm-heap(2391): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.978MB for 2049424-byte allocation
11-26 08:41:34.216: D/dalvikvm(2391): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 3% free 5031K/5152K, paused 183ms, total 183ms
11-26 08:41:35.016: D/gralloc_goldfish(2391): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
11-26 08:41:35.426: I/ActivityManager(371): Displayed com.thenewboston.christoph/.Splash: +4s121ms (total +2m18s290ms)
11-26 08:41:39.536: I/ActivityManager(371): START u0 {act=com.thenewboston.christoph.STARTINGPOINT cmp=com.thenewboston.christoph/.StartingPoint} from pid 2391
11-26 08:41:39.566: D/gralloc(52): Registering a buffer in the process that created it. This may cause memory ordering problems.
11-26 08:41:39.566: E/libEGL(52): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
11-26 08:41:39.566: E/libEGL(52): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
11-26 08:41:39.566: E/libEGL(52): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
11-26 08:41:39.576: E/libEGL(52): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
11-26 08:41:39.576: E/SurfaceFlinger(52): glCheckFramebufferStatusOES error 552518609
11-26 08:41:39.576: E/SurfaceFlinger(52): got GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES error while taking screenshot
11-26 08:41:39.576: E/libEGL(52): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
11-26 08:41:39.576: E/libEGL(52): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
11-26 08:41:39.576: W/WindowManager(371): Screenshot failure taking screenshot for (328x583) to layer 21010
11-26 08:41:39.706: D/AndroidRuntime(2391): Shutting down VM
11-26 08:41:39.706: W/dalvikvm(2391): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1adfb90)
11-26 08:41:39.846: E/AndroidRuntime(2391): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-26 08:41:39.846: E/AndroidRuntime(2391): Process: com.thenewboston.christoph, PID: 2391
11-26 08:41:39.846: E/AndroidRuntime(2391): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.thenewboston.christoph/com.thenewboston.christoph.StartingPoint}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-26 08:41:39.846: E/AndroidRuntime(2391):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
11-26 08:41:39.846: E/AndroidRuntime(2391):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
11-26 08:41:39.846: E/AndroidRuntime(2391):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
11-26 08:41:39.846: E/AndroidRuntime(2391):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
11-26 08:41:39.846: E/AndroidRuntime(2391):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-26 08:41:39.846: E/AndroidRuntime(2391):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-26 08:41:39.846: E/AndroidRuntime(2391):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
11-26 08:41:39.846: E/AndroidRuntime(2391):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-26 08:41:39.846: E/AndroidRuntime(2391):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-26 08:41:39.846: E/AndroidRuntime(2391):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
11-26 08:41:39.846: E/AndroidRuntime(2391):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
11-26 08:41:39.846: E/AndroidRuntime(2391):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-26 08:41:39.846: E/AndroidRuntime(2391): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-26 08:41:39.846: E/AndroidRuntime(2391):     at com.thenewboston.christoph.StartingPoint.onCreate(StartingPoint.java:32)
11-26 08:41:39.846: E/AndroidRuntime(2391):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
11-26 08:41:39.846: E/AndroidRuntime(2391):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
11-26 08:41:39.846: E/AndroidRuntime(2391):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
11-26 08:41:39.846: E/AndroidRuntime(2391):     ... 11 more
11-26 08:41:39.986: W/ActivityManager(371):   Force finishing activity com.thenewboston.christoph/.StartingPoint
11-26 08:41:42.186: W/ActivityManager(371): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{b20bd328 u0 com.thenewboston.christoph/.StartingPoint t35 f}
11-26 08:41:44.446: I/Choreographer(371): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-26 08:41:45.026: E/SoundPool(371): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-26 08:41:45.026: W/AudioService(371): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-26 08:41:45.026: E/SoundPool(371): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-26 08:41:45.026: W/AudioService(371): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-26 08:41:45.026: E/SoundPool(371): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-26 08:41:45.026: W/AudioService(371): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-26 08:41:45.026: E/SoundPool(371): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-26 08:41:45.026: W/AudioService(371): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-26 08:41:45.036: E/SoundPool(371): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-26 08:41:45.036: W/AudioService(371): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-26 08:41:45.036: E/SoundPool(371): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
11-26 08:41:45.036: W/AudioService(371): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
11-26 08:41:45.036: E/SoundPool(371): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
11-26 08:41:45.036: W/AudioService(371): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
11-26 08:41:45.036: E/SoundPool(371): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
11-26 08:41:45.036: W/AudioService(371): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
11-26 08:41:45.036: E/SoundPool(371): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
11-26 08:41:45.036: W/AudioService(371): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
11-26 08:41:45.036: E/SoundPool(371): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
11-26 08:41:45.036: W/AudioService(371): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
11-26 08:41:45.036: W/AudioService(371): onLoadSoundEffects(), Error -1 while loading samples
11-26 08:41:45.356: I/Process(2391): Sending signal. PID: 2391 SIG: 9
11-26 08:41:45.406: I/ActivityManager(371): Process com.thenewboston.christoph (pid 2391) has died.
11-26 08:41:45.436: I/WindowState(371): WIN DEATH: Window{b20c73c8 u0 com.thenewboston.christoph/com.thenewboston.christoph.Splash}
11-26 08:41:45.446: I/Choreographer(371): Skipped 50 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-26 08:41:45.466: W/Looper(371): Ignoring unexpected epoll events 0x11 on fd 181 that is no longer registered.
11-26 08:41:48.566: W/InputMethodManagerService(371): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 2391 uid 10051
11-26 08:41:48.586: W/Binder(505): Caught a RuntimeException from the binder stub implementation.
11-26 08:41:48.586: W/Binder(505): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-26 08:41:48.586: W/Binder(505):  at android.inputmethodservice.IInputMethodWrapper.setSessionEnabled(IInputMethodWrapper.java:280)
11-26 08:41:48.586: W/Binder(505):  at com.android.internal.view.IInputMethod$Stub.onTransact(IInputMethod.java:129)
11-26 08:41:48.586: W/Binder(505):  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
11-26 08:41:48.586: W/Binder(505):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
11-26 08:41:48.676: I/Choreographer(531): Skipped 97 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-26 08:41:48.786: W/WindowManager(371): Rebuild removed 2 windows but added 1
11-26 08:41:48.786: W/WindowManager(371): java.lang.RuntimeException: here
11-26 08:41:48.786: W/WindowManager(371):   at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.rebuildAppWindowListLocked(WindowManagerService.java:7985)
11-26 08:41:48.786: W/WindowManager(371):   at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.rebuildAppWindowListLocked(WindowManagerService.java:7921)
11-26 08:41:48.786: W/WindowManager(371):   at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.handleAnimatingStoppedAndTransitionLocked(WindowManagerService.java:8660)
11-26 08:41:48.786: W/WindowManager(371):   at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.performLayoutAndPlaceSurfacesLockedInner(WindowManagerService.java:9183)
11-26 08:41:48.786: W/WindowManager(371):   at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.performLayoutAndPlaceSurfacesLockedLoop(WindowManagerService.java:8137)
11-26 08:41:48.786: W/WindowManager(371):   at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.performLayoutAndPlaceSurfacesLocked(WindowManagerService.java:8079)
11-26 08:41:48.786: W/WindowManager(371):   at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.access$300(WindowManagerService.java:157)
11-26 08:41:48.786: W/WindowManager(371):   at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService$H.handleMessage(WindowManagerService.java:7139)
11-26 08:41:48.786: W/WindowManager(371):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-26 08:41:48.786: W/WindowManager(371):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-26 08:41:48.786: W/WindowManager(371):   at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
11-26 08:41:48.796: W/WindowManager(371): This window was lost: Window{b20c73c8 u0 com.thenewboston.christoph/com.thenewboston.christoph.Splash}
11-26 08:41:48.796: W/WindowManager(371): mDisplayId=0 mSession=Session{b208dd60 2391:u0a10051} mClient=android.os.BinderProxy@b208a2a0
11-26 08:41:48.796: W/WindowManager(371): mOwnerUid=10051 mShowToOwnerOnly=true package=com.thenewboston.christoph appop=NONE
11-26 08:41:48.796: W/WindowManager(371): mAttrs=WM.LayoutParams{(0,0)(fillxfill) sim=#120 ty=1 fl=#1810100 pfl=0x8 wanim=0x10302a1}
11-26 08:41:48.796: W/WindowManager(371): Requested w=720 h=1184 mLayoutSeq=921
11-26 08:41:48.796: W/WindowManager(371): mBaseLayer=21000 mSubLayer=0 mAnimLayer=21005+0=21005 mLastLayer=21005
11-26 08:41:48.796: W/WindowManager(371): mToken=AppWindowToken{b230b600 token=Token{b201ba40 ActivityRecord{b206c920 u0 com.thenewboston.christoph/.Splash t35}}}
11-26 08:41:48.796: W/WindowManager(371): mRootToken=AppWindowToken{b230b600 token=Token{b201ba40 ActivityRecord{b206c920 u0 com.thenewboston.christoph/.Splash t35}}}
11-26 08:41:48.796: W/WindowManager(371): mAppToken=AppWindowToken{b230b600 token=Token{b201ba40 ActivityRecord{b206c920 u0 com.thenewboston.christoph/.Splash t35}}}
11-26 08:41:48.796: W/WindowManager(371): mViewVisibility=0x0 mHaveFrame=true mObscured=false
11-26 08:41:48.796: W/WindowManager(371): mSeq=0 mSystemUiVisibility=0x0
11-26 08:41:48.796: W/WindowManager(371): mGivenContentInsets=[0,0][0,0] mGivenVisibleInsets=[0,0][0,0]
11-26 08:41:48.796: W/WindowManager(371): mConfiguration={1.0 310mcc260mnc en_US ldltr sw360dp w360dp h567dp 320dpi nrml port finger qwerty/v/v -nav/h s.5}
11-26 08:41:48.796: W/WindowManager(371): mHasSurface=true mShownFrame=[0.0,0.0][720.0,1184.0] isReadyForDisplay()=false
11-26 08:41:48.796: W/WindowManager(371): mFrame=[0,0][720,1184] last=[0,0][720,1184]
11-26 08:41:48.796: W/WindowManager(371): mSystemDecorRect=[0,50][720,1184] last=[0,50][720,1184]
11-26 08:41:48.796: W/WindowManager(371): Frames: containing=[0,0][720,1184] parent=[0,0][720,1184]
11-26 08:41:48.796: W/WindowManager(371):     display=[0,0][720,1184] overscan=[0,0][720,1280]
11-26 08:41:48.796: W/WindowManager(371):     content=[0,50][720,1184] visible=[0,50][720,1184]
11-26 08:41:48.796: W/WindowManager(371):     decor=[0,50][720,1184]
11-26 08:41:48.796: W/WindowManager(371): Cur insets: overscan=[0,0][0,0] content=[0,50][0,0] visible=[0,50][0,0]
11-26 08:41:48.796: W/WindowManager(371): Lst insets: overscan=[0,0][0,0] content=[0,50][0,0] visible=[0,50][0,0]
11-26 08:41:48.796: W/WindowManager(371): WindowStateAnimator{b22c8a08 com.thenewboston.christoph/com.thenewboston.christoph.Splash}:
11-26 08:41:48.796: W/WindowManager(371):   mSurface=Surface(name=com.thenewboston.christoph/com.thenewboston.christoph.Splash)
11-26 08:41:48.796: W/WindowManager(371):   mDrawState=HAS_DRAWN mLastHidden=true
11-26 08:41:48.796: W/WindowManager(371):   Surface: shown=false layer=21005 alpha=1.0 rect=(0.0,0.0) 720.0 x 1184.0
11-26 08:41:48.796: W/WindowManager(371):   mGlobalScale=1.0 mDsDx=1.0 mDtDx=0.0 mDsDy=0.0 mDtDy=1.0
11-26 08:41:48.796: W/WindowManager(371): mExiting=false mRemoveOnExit=false mDestroying=true mRemoved=false
11-26 08:41:48.806: W/WindowManager(371): Current app token list:
11-26 08:41:48.806: V/WindowManager(371):   Display 0
11-26 08:41:48.816: V/WindowManager(371):   #1: Token{b207c918 ActivityRecord{b1fee0f8 u0 com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher t1}}
11-26 08:41:48.856: V/WindowManager(371):   #0: Token{b233b8f8 ActivityRecord{b2094c38 u0 com.android.quicksearchbox/.SearchActivity t20}}
11-26 08:41:48.856: W/WindowManager(371): Final window list:
11-26 08:41:48.856: V/WindowManager(371):   #0: Window{b1f7c708 u0 SearchPanel}
11-26 08:41:48.856: V/WindowManager(371):   #1: Window{b1fb8890 u0 NavigationBar}
11-26 08:41:48.856: V/WindowManager(371):   #2: Window{b20b8e70 u0 StatusBar}
11-26 08:41:48.856: V/WindowManager(371):   #3: Window{b2011000 u0 Keyguard}
11-26 08:41:48.856: V/WindowManager(371):   #4: Window{b1fabae8 u0 KeyguardScrim}
11-26 08:41:48.856: V/WindowManager(371):   #5: Window{b20b1338 u0 com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher}
11-26 08:41:48.856: V/WindowManager(371):   #6: Window{b1ffe8b0 u0 com.android.systemui.ImageWallpaper}
11-26 08:41:49.596: W/ActivityManager(371): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
```

Comment: Working with Media Player???

Comment: I meant in my code. I excluded the sound file again. But I got the sound to work. However, the app still stopps running after releasing my first class.

Comment: Post your code here...

Comment: Its the code I posted above. I reposted my opening topic with the new failure code because its too long for the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Change this code like this

```
add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSub);
display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
11-26 05:17:44.106: E/AndroidRuntime(2209): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-26 05:17:44.106: E/AndroidRuntime(2209):     at com.thenewboston.christoph.StartingPoint.onCreate(StartingPoint.java:32)
```

There is your problem, most likely your "add" (try naming your fields in a more relevant way, like btnAdd) is null for some reason.

Also as RajaReddy PolamReddy mentioned, you need to cast it to Button by adding (Button) before findViewById, cause this method returns a View instance, not a Button.